# JAXB (new) annotation

Tags: annotations, jaxb, comments

If you have some Java class:

```
@XmlType(namespace="")
@XmlRootElement(name="", namespace="")
public class Car 
{

    // This is some comment
    @XmlElement()
    private long id;
...
```

And you want to create schema like this (with comment inside schema):

```
<xs:complexType name="Car ">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:documentation> This is some comment</xs:documentation>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there way how to configure JAXB?
I have think, is there way how to create "new annotation", so my Java class would look like:

```
@XmlType(namespace="")
@XmlRootElement(name="", namespace="")
public class Car 
{

    @XmlDoc("This is some comment")
    @XmlElement()
    private long id;
...
```

In other words: can I tell jaxb, that new annotation is important to him and how it should be "parsed" in context.generateSchema (schemaOutputResolver)

(As example: @XmlDoc is new annotation and jaxb should take its value and put in xs: document element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**:  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This functionality does not currently exist today, but it has been requested before:

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-273

There is also an open enhancement request where we are gather the requirements to add this type of feature to MOXy.  I would be interested in getting your thoughts on it:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/409419